# What could SIGABRT on last line of main (error code 6) mean C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, program-entry-point, clion, sigabrt

I'm learning C++ and just starting multithreading (a really basic form). I am getting A SIGABRT with the message "libc++abi.dylib: terminating" and Exit Code 6. This wouldn't be weird except this error shows up on the last curly brace of my main function. Any ideas on what could be causing such a weird issue?

Comment: Without code we can only guess.  Probably something in a destructor that is called on for a local variable in main that has been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a multithreading app, know that you need to wait for your threads to finish before exiting the application, by using the `join()` function.

Otherwise the program exits while the thread is still running, earning you a crash.